# How to show results by Category in SQL and display in classic ASP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table from where I want to display records on the page grouped by categories in Classic ASP in such order that the Latest records are displayed on top. I am using MS SQL 2005 server.
For example table is like

```
ID  Data1  Data2  Category
1     abc   def    test1
2     rrr   344    test2
3     ttt   edf    test1
4     www   ghj    test2
```

sql="select * from TABLE where Category='test1" and Category='test2' order by ID desc"

I want to display the all the data from category Test1 and Test2 on the page at different places. How to separate results by category?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you using software that has been unsupported for many *years*?  Your `where` clause is incorrect.  Your query cannot return any rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to display the results in different places, just run both SQL statements and store the results into 2 different Recordsets.

```
<% 
set rs1=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
set rs2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

SQL1="select * from TABLE where Category='test1' order by ID desc"
SQL2="select * from TABLE where Category='test2' order by ID desc"

rs1.Open SQL1, ConnectionString
rs2.Open SQL2, ConnectionString

Test1_ID       = rs1("ID")
Test1_Data1    = rs1("Data1)
Test1_Data2    = rs1("Data2")
Test1_Category = rs1("Category")

Test2_ID       = rs2("ID")
Test2_Data1    = rs2("Data1")
Test2_Data2    = rs2("Data2")
Test2_Category = rs2("Category")
%>
```

This code assumes you already have set your connection string = ConnectionString and have already opened it, and side note, you can share the connection, or you can make one for each recordset, if its not that much data it won't matter, but if its a larger chunk of data, it wouldn't hurt to have 2 connection objects.

Now when you go to display the results you can just rs1.MoveNext to move to the next record in the first set, and rs2.MoveNext to move to the next record in the second recordset. Your question was how to be able to display the records in different places, so now you have the variables names and a way to move to the next record, if you know how to move through a loop advancing the recordsets until you reach the last record, you just do that for both recordsets, and as each one is being done and displayed, they will be separate until you write the part to display the results from rs2 as well.

Closing Notes - In case you need to be specific in your SQL, you can specify the source in the format of database.tablename.  So in the example you would do something like this for SQL1:

```
select * from DATABASE.TABLE where Category='test1' order by ID desc
```

Comment: This is terrible advice, suggesting two database connections when the same can be done with one connection horrendous solution. This wouldn’t make it past QA in our team.

Comment: I said in this instance it isn't needed, but when you get more advanced query requirements later, some old ASP tricks from yore show numerical gains in cases where you might need one connection for a select and another for an insert, and idealistically you could combine them into one.   If your resources are so slim on your server that 2 connections would be a problem, I worry about your QA team.